# How can I use the OR operator with optional binding?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a piece of code that I would like to execute if a variable can be casted as one of two types.

```
if let myOptional = variableToCast as! firstTypeToTryToCastAs || 
   let myOptional = variableToCast as! secondTypeToTryToCastAs {
        //Execute some code
}
```

However, Swift (as of version 2.0) apparently does not allow this. I'm looking for a way to do this without having to create two separate `if` blocks.

My code only uses the super type, therefore the code dealing with both types are the same. However, I can't cast it to the super type because I don't want to code to execute if variableToCast is one of the many other possible types that are also derived from the same super type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> My code only uses the super type, therefore the code dealing with both
>   types are the same. However, I can't cast it to the super type because
>   I don't want to code to execute if variableToCast is one of the many
>   other possible types that are also derived from the same super type.

In your *optional binding* `if let` cast to the super type and then limit it to the classes you are interested in with a `where` clause:

```
class SuperType {

}

class firstTypeToTryToCastAs: SuperType {

}

class secondTypeToTryToCastAs: SuperType {

}

class thirdTypeToTryToCastAs: SuperType {

}

var variableToCast: AnyObject = firstTypeToTryToCastAs()

if let myOptional = variableToCast as? SuperType where myOptional is firstTypeToTryToCastAs || myOptional is secondTypeToTryToCastAs {
    print("this works")
} else {
    print("not the type we are looking for")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way to do this without having to create two separate if blocks

Why?

You can't use the same code in the if block anyway because `myOptional` will be of a different type.  I would go with

```
if let myOptional = variableToCast as! firstTypeToTryToCastAs
{
    // code dealing with a firstTypeToTryToCastAs
}
else if let myOptional = variableToCast as! secondTypeToTryToCastAs
{
    // code dealing with a secondTypeToTryToCastAs
}
```

On the other hand if your two types have a common super type, cast it to that super type.

Comment: My code only uses the super type, therefore the code dealing with both types are the same. However, I can't cast it to the super type because I don't want to code to execute if `variableToCast` is one of the many other possible types that are also derived from the same super type.

Comment: @FarhadYusufali the above comment is a pretty essential part of the question.  You should consider editing the question to put the same information in it.  This will help people in future who have a similar problem to yours.

Comment: @JeremyP, that was a good suggestion.  I went ahead and updated the question with Farhad's comment in case he didn't get around to it for a while.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks, I was considering doing it myself but I thought I'd give Farhad the chance.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto JeremyP's answer, if you don't actually care what the value of myOptional is, but just want to execute some code if it is one of those two types, you could do this instead

```
if variableToCast is firstTypeToTryToCastAs || variableToCast is secondTypeToTryToCastAs {
    //Code for both cases
}
```